# Copying dropdown values

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, copy

I'm trying to copy two dropdown values and add them to a textarea. I copy one just fine but can't copy two. I'm trying to copy the value of 'amount' and the value of 'type' combine them and insert into a textarea. My code:

```
function copy() {
    var sel = document.getElementById("amount");

    var text = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    var out = document.getElementById("textarea");
    out.value += text + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sel1 = document.getElementById("amount");
var sel2 = document.getElementByid("type");
var amt = sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value;
var typ = sel2.options[sel2.selectedIndex].value;
var out = document.getElementById("textarea");
out.value += amt + " " + typ + "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to rename your field named "type" as that could very possibly be a reserved variable name.

Also, I don't see where you are pulling in the value of type?  Try this:

```
function copy() {
    var sel = document.getElementById("amount");
    var textInput = document.getElementById("some_type");
    var text = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value + textInput.value;
    var out = document.getElementById("textarea");
    out.value += text + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Epsil!  Corrected above.

Comment: both of these solutions work.  However they only allow me to pull in values from a dropdown box.  I need to pull in a value from a dropdown as well as textfield.

Comment: Hey user, I edited my answer to use a test input and a dropdown input.